# How do I get GhostScript to load TTF fonts globally?

Tags: pdf, fonts, ghostscript, imagemagick-convert

I am using PHP's Imagick to convert PDFs to JPEGs.  Some of the PDFs have a custom TTF font that is not embedded in the PDF, so I need to install it on my file system.  I believe that GhostScript actually does the converting, so that's where I've been spending most of my time trying to get the font to load.

When I run `gs -help` I get:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.15 (2014-09-22)
Copyright (C) 2014 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
Usage: gs [switches] [file1.ps file2.ps ...]
Most frequently used switches: (you can use # in place of =)
 -dNOPAUSE           no pause after page   | -q       `quiet', fewer messages
 -g<width>x<height>  page size in pixels   | -r<res>  pixels/inch resolution
 -sDEVICE=<devname>  select device         | -dBATCH  exit after last file
 -sOutputFile=<file> select output file: - for stdout, |command for pipe,
                                     embed %d or %ld for page #
Input formats: PostScript PostScriptLevel1 PostScriptLevel2 PostScriptLevel3 PDF
Default output device: x11alpha
Available devices:
   alc1900 alc2000 alc4000 alc4100 alc8500 alc8600 alc9100 ap3250 appledmp
   atx23 atx24 atx38 bbox bit bitcmyk bitrgb bitrgbtags bj10e bj10v bj10vh
   bj200 bjc600 bjc800 bjc880j bjccmyk bjccolor bjcgray bjcmono bmp16 bmp16m
   bmp256 bmp32b bmpgray bmpmono bmpsep1 bmpsep8 ccr cdeskjet cdj1600 cdj500
   cdj550 cdj670 cdj850 cdj880 cdj890 cdj970 cdjcolor cdjmono cdnj500 cfax
   chp2200 cif cljet5 cljet5c cljet5pr coslw2p coslwxl cp50 cups declj250
   deskjet devicen dfaxhigh dfaxlow dj505j djet500 djet500c dl2100 dnj650c
   epl2050 epl2050p epl2120 epl2500 epl2750 epl5800 epl5900 epl6100 epl6200
   eplcolor eplmono eps2write eps9high eps9mid epson epsonc escp escpage
   faxg3 faxg32d faxg4 fmlbp fmpr fpng fs600 gdi hl1240 hl1250 hl7x0
   hpdj1120c hpdj310 hpdj320 hpdj340 hpdj400 hpdj500 hpdj500c hpdj510
   hpdj520 hpdj540 hpdj550c hpdj560c hpdj600 hpdj660c hpdj670c hpdj680c
   hpdj690c hpdj850c hpdj855c hpdj870c hpdj890c hpdjplus hpdjportable ibmpro
   ijs imagen inferno ink_cov inkcov itk24i itk38 iwhi iwlo iwlq jetp3852
   jj100 jpeg jpegcmyk jpeggray la50 la70 la75 la75plus laserjet lbp310
   lbp320 lbp8 lex2050 lex3200 lex5700 lex7000 lips2p lips3 lips4 lips4v
   lj250 lj3100sw lj4dith lj4dithp lj5gray lj5mono ljet2p ljet3 ljet3d ljet4
   ljet4d ljet4pjl ljetplus ln03 lp1800 lp1900 lp2000 lp2200 lp2400 lp2500
   lp2563 lp3000c lp7500 lp7700 lp7900 lp8000 lp8000c lp8100 lp8200c lp8300c
   lp8300f lp8400f lp8500c lp8600 lp8600f lp8700 lp8800c lp8900 lp9000b
   lp9000c lp9100 lp9200b lp9200c lp9300 lp9400 lp9500c lp9600 lp9600s
   lp9800c lps4500 lps6500 lq850 lxm3200 lxm5700m m8510 mag16 mag256
   md1xMono md2k md50Eco md50Mono md5k mgr4 mgr8 mgrgray2 mgrgray4 mgrgray8
   mgrmono miff24 mj500c mj6000c mj700v2c mj8000c ml600 necp6 npdl nullpage
   oce9050 oki182 oki4w okiibm oprp opvp paintjet pam pamcmyk32 pamcmyk4 pbm
   pbmraw pcl3 pcx16 pcx24b pcx256 pcx2up pcxcmyk pcxgray pcxmono pdfwrite
   pgm pgmraw pgnm pgnmraw photoex picty180 pj pjetxl pjxl pjxl300 pkm
   pkmraw pksm pksmraw plan plan9bm planc plang plank planm png16 png16m
   png256 png48 pngalpha pnggray pngmono pnm pnmraw ppm ppmraw pr1000
   pr1000_4 pr150 pr201 ps2write psdcmyk psdcmykog psdrgb pxlcolor pxlmono
   r4081 rinkj rpdl samsunggdi sgirgb sj48 spotcmyk st800 stcolor sunhmono
   t4693d2 t4693d4 t4693d8 tek4696 tiff12nc tiff24nc tiff32nc tiff48nc
   tiff64nc tiffcrle tiffg3 tiffg32d tiffg4 tiffgray tifflzw tiffpack
   tiffscaled tiffsep tiffsep1 txtwrite uniprint x11 x11alpha x11cmyk
   x11cmyk2 x11cmyk4 x11cmyk8 x11gray2 x11gray4 x11mono x11rg16x x11rg32x
   xcf xes xpswrite
Search path:
   %rom%Resource/Init/ : %rom%lib/ :
   /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.15/Resource/Init :
   /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.15/lib :
   /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.15/Resource/Font :
   /usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts :
   /usr/local/share/fonts/default/ghostscript :
   /usr/local/share/fonts/default/Type1 :
   /usr/local/share/fonts/default/TrueType : /usr/lib/DPS/outline/base :
   /usr/openwin/lib/X11/fonts/Type1 : /usr/openwin/lib/X11/fonts/TrueType :
   /usr/share/cups/fonts
Ghostscript is also using fontconfig to search for font files
Initialization files are compiled into the executable.
For more information, see /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.15/doc/Use.htm.
Please report bugs to bugs.ghostscript.com.
```

From this,  I can see /usr/local/share/fonts/default/TrueType in my Search paths.  I uploaded GLFONT.TTF to that folder.  I then added to /usr/share/ghostscript/8.70/Resource/Init/Fontmap.GS the following at the bottom of the file `/GLFont[tab](GLFONT.TTF)[tab];`.  I believe this to be the correct syntax for the fontmap file.

When I run the commad `gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -sOutputFile=test.jpg www/product_images/test.pdf`  I get the following output:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.15 (2014-09-22)
Copyright (C) 2014 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
Substituting font Times-Roman for GLFont.
Loading NimbusRomNo9L-Regu font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusRomNo9L-Regu... 4499544 2930395 9030496 7679326 3 done.`
```

So, you can see the font isn't recognized.  However, when I specify my font directory with `gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -sOutputFile=test.jpg -sFONTPATH=/usr/local/share/fonts/default/TrueType www/product_images/test.pdf` the font is found:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.15 (2014-09-22)
Copyright (C) 2014 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
Scanning /usr/local/share/fonts/default/TrueType for fonts... 1 files, 1 scanned, 1 new fonts.
Loading GLFont font from /usr/local/share/fonts/default/TrueType/GLFONT.TTF... 4509572 2891739 9232600 7842698 3 done.
```

Any ideas on how to debug why the font isn't being loaded globally from the fontmap?

Answer (score 1):

Well you have apparently edited the font map for Ghostscript 8.70, judging by the path you supply (*/usr/share/ghostscript/8.70/Resource/Init/Fontmap.GS*).

But from the *stdout* output, you are using Ghostscript 9.15.

Now its possible that your environment is set up so that Ghostscript reads the 8.70 `fontmap.GS`, but at a guess I would say it doesn't (the output from `gs -help` would probably be useful here).

Also, you haven't specified a full path for the TTF in the `fontmap.GS` file. You might want to try that too. Posting the actual output from `gs -help` would be useful as well of course.

Comment: Ah, the different versions make sense.  I've posted the `gs -help` output in my post above.  I tried to find fontmaps associated with 9.15 and there weren't any.  In fact when I went to `/usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.15/` the Resource directory didn't even exist.  So, I copied over the fontmaps and structure from 8.70 and put in the full path of the TTF file and still no luck.  Do I need to do anything to make GS aware of a new Fontmap or should it just parse that directory and see it?

Comment: Its possible (perhaps even likely) that your Ghostscript build is using a ROM file system. In fact I see from the gs -help that it is. That means that the Resource files are stored in the executable. If you want to alter any of them you'll need to get hold of the source for Ghostscript and put the 'Resource' folders and their contents somewhere convenient. Then you need to tell Ghostscript to use that folder, -sGenericResourceDir= should do the trick I think. *Then* you can modify the fontmap.GS in there successfully.

Comment: I should have noted that it *is* using the files in usr/local/share/Ghostscript/9.15 if those are present, but I think it searches %rom% first (according to the search order in the gs -help). If the files are present there, you can just point -sGenericResourceDir=/usr/local/share/Ghostscript/9.15/Resource

Comment: Setting the GenericResourceDir works, but seems to get me in the same spot as setting the FontPath.  It works from the command line, but when Imagick calls it the font is still not loaded.  That's why I was thinking I needed to do something to get the font to load globally without doing anything special in the command line.  Sounds like my only real option here is to reinstall GS from the source to get it to not use the ROM system, correct?

Comment: Well ImageMagick won't (presumably) be setting the GenericResourceDir on the command line when it calls GS. You can build a version of Ghostscript which has a modified fontmap.GS in the ROM file system. You can build a non-ROMfs version of GS (but *something* will still have to point to the resources, probably an environment variable) or you can modify the ImageMagick parameters being used.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a path to a TTF folder using the environment variable **GS_FONTPATH**

You can also specify the TTF path via the commandline switch  **-sFONTPATH=**

e.g. On my Windows machine I made a system wide environment variable,
**GS_FONTPATH=C:\Windows\Fonts**

Reference: [How to Use Ghostscript - Font lookup](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#Font_lookup)